# Cocos2d supports Multithreading or not?

Tags: multithreading

I am making cocos2d program and want to use threads. Does cocos2d support threading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Cocoa does support Multithreading. Check this [article](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH6-SW2)